# How to make nether into all air

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to make my nether all air nether but the portal. I have mcedit so I can use that but don't know how.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: For a custom map im making

Comment: You might be better off using a mod like Mystcraft to create a void world and using crystal portals instead.

Answer (score 3):

### Simple Mod-Free Answer:

[image: and lots of it, too.]

### Complex Answer:

First off, do not use MCEdit unless you know how. It can be pure dangerous. Fortunately, there are many MCEdit tutorials online.

I personally recommend using WorldEdit. It exists for 1.7.10 as a forge mod, and is pretty good. Select a big area that you want to clear by doing `//wand` and selecting two corners of said area. Then type `//set air`. Cleaned up!